# How to enable 3 screens on HP EliteBook 8570p with Intel SPU and HD4000 integrated graphics card?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, hp-elitebook

I'm trying to enable 3 displays in EliteBook 8570p. I see that 3 monitors are detected, built-in and two external connected into dock station with DVI. I tried reconnect directly into laptop as DVI / VGA without result.
Always one of three displays is grayed. Computer generate video signal only for two monitors, it is no matter which one of them.

I'm using Windows7 Pro. Computer has APU, Intel i5-3360M 2.8GHz with Intel HD Graphics 4000 .

Making extremely low resolution (800x600) gives no results.

UPDATE:

First monitor is laptop integrated display. Two external monitors are connected via DVI to dock station. I tried to connect one of them by VGA analog classic cable to dock station, or reconnect it to port in VGA socket in laptop body, but it behaves the same. The same is when one of monitor is connected into DisplayPort with HDMI-DP adapter, because no one monitor I have got, has no DP socket.

I thought serviced pixels are main problem, but all is the same when I go down resolution on all monitors into 800x600 pixels. Dock station doesn't have any graphics, it works as adapter for monitors.

Some of people told me, it is impossible using 3rd monitor with integrated graphics, but I saw some info on internet that it is possible. I didn't test it with HDMI, because I haven't got any equipment for this, but dock station has got two HDMI sockets.

Comment: As I've understood you're using dock station connected to the laptop. Can you specify models of displays? Can you specify through which graphic interfaces (e.g. HDMI,DVI,VGA) are these displays connected to the dock station? You also might want to check Intel's faq: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/graphics-drivers/000005556.html

Comment: I added some details in question description. thank you for intel link,maybe it will help me. I tryed find this info in HP pages because it is manufacturer.

Comment: What is the model of your dock station? Is it VB041AA? You can find a model of your dock station via this link: http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03247469

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your chipset ([Mobile Intel QM77 Express (vPro support))](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03393927)) it does not support more than two monitors. You can have a closer look on your chipset specifications on the [Intel official website](http://ark.intel.com/products/64333/Intel-BD82QM77-PCH).

Comment: Unfortunately yes, i have got QM77 chipset :(

Answer (score 1):

I just found this post, but I had the AMD graphics and I still had the same problem, so I hope it is on-topic enough to post my solution here:

1. At least one of the outputs needs to be using the DisplayPort.
2. If you do not have a DisplayPort input on your screen, you MUST use an ACTIVE DisplayPort Adapter.
3. So if you want DVI, you have to use an Active DisplayPort to DVI adapter. Stupid but works.

Also note, you probably can't use the DisplayPort and DVI port on the Basic Dock at the same time - they apparently share the same channel. But you can use the DisplayPort and VGA port at the same time. Same principle for the Advanced Dock, just x2.

Just to add details:

- I now have a Basic Dock (optional) with Active DisplayPort to HDMI adapter for 1 screen, and VGA for the other screen.
- When I had a Passive DisplayPort to HDMI adapter, this setup failed in every possible configuration.
- Specs say its a maximum of 3 displays with the Basic Dock (and presumably with no dock).
- And a maximum of 4 displays with the Advanced Dock.

Comment: I have advanced dock station. It has to ports groups, first is VGA+DVI+DP, second is DVI+DP. In the one group I can use only one port. Third port is internal for build in laptop screen. I can select two of three available screens, all is recognized. Unfortunately I have not active DP-to-any video adapter. Unfortunately I found info, in my laptop is chipset version that doesn't support 3 active screen. Then it is laptop harware limitation. Then I can use internal screen with single external,or two externals without internal. It is independed on adapters. For AMD solutions itis much better:)